# Edit Pdf Bookmark Action to open a Url (Python or workarounds)

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, bookmarks, pypdf

I have pdfs where I'm adding bookmarks in Python. I would like to add some bookmarks which open a website url instead of going to a page in the current document. This is very easy inside Adobe Acrobat, you just have to change the bookmark action to "Open a web link". However I can't find any way with Python or other methods (eg QPDF) to achieve this. **How can I change a bookmark action (or add a new one) to opening a website url with Python or a workaround method?**

My current code for adding regular bookmarks:

```
def AddBookmarks(inputPdfPath: str, headers: dict) -> str:
    """ Adds bookmarks to a PDF. """

    output = PdfFileWriter()
    outputPdfPath = inputPdfPath.replace(".pdf", "_with_bookmarks.pdf")
    input = PdfFileReader(open(inputPdfPath, 'rb'))

    for i in range(input.getNumPages()):
        output.addPage(input.getPage(i))

        for header in headers:
            if header["Page"] - 1 == i:

                output.addBookmark(header["Title"], header["Page"] - 1, parent=None) 
                output.setPageMode("/UseOutlines")

    outputStream = open(outputPdfPath,'wb')
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()

    return outputPdfPath
```

[image]

If it helps, this is how a url bookmark part looks in the raw pdf code:

```
%% Object stream: object 106, index 99; original object ID: 1881
<<
  /S /URI
  /URI (http://www.google.com)
>>
endstream
endobj
```

Answer (score 1):

I've investigated the issue and have managed to find the answer. It's not my most efficient/nicest code but definitely one of my proudest since nobody before did this.

The problem one faces is that there is no Pdf library for python that solves all pdf related problems. Each tackle problems differently and some can do stuff that others can't. For this purpose, I had to use 2 libraries for the two functions below. `PyPDF2` is here to add the bookmarks to the pdf. `Pdfrw` is here to alter those bookmarks to have the action of opening a url.

In short, we create a new pdf with the added bookmarks, and another new one with the changed bookmarks actions that point to a url.

One thing to mention is that for some reason (for me at least) `PyPDF2` adds all bookmarks in a way that if you have multiple ones, they all become child elements to the previous bookmark. this is why we have the while loop, we collect all the bookmarks into a list with it, and then we can select the one we want.

If you already have bookmars and don't add them with `PyPDF2`, it might be enough to just loop over the `metaObjects` dictionary and get the values which contain the `/Title key`. Thus making the code significantly smaller. I've added this part as a comment.

I've written an example at the end.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import pdfrw

def AddBookmarks(inputPdfPath: str, outputPdfPath: str, headers: dict) -> None:
    """ Adds bookmarks to a PDF. """

    output = PdfFileWriter()
    input = PdfFileReader(open(inputPdfPath, 'rb'))

    for i in range(input.getNumPages()):
        output.addPage(input.getPage(i))
        for header in headers:
            if header["Page"] - 1 == i:
                output.addBookmark(header["Title"], header["Page"] - 1, parent=None) 
                output.setPageMode("/UseOutlines")

    outputStream = open(outputPdfPath,'wb')
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()

    return outputPdfPath

def AddWebLinkToBookmark(inputPdfPath: str, outputPdfPath: str, bookmarkTitle: str, url: str) -> None:
    """ Changes to bookmark action to opening a web url. """

    # Reading the Pdf with pdfrw and collecting its meta objects. The bookmarks are among these.
    pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(inputPdfPath, decompress=True)
    metaObjects = pdf.indirect_objects

    # If you did not add the bookmarks with PyPDF2 previously, use this part for getting the bookmarkToChange variable:
    # bookmarkToChange = None
    # for _, annotation in metaObjects.items():
    #     if '/Title' in annotation:
    #         if annotation["/Title"] == f"({bookmarkTitle})".replace(" ", "\\040"):
    #             bookmarkToChange = annotation
    # if bookmarkToChange == None:
    #     print(f"There is no bookmark called '{bookmarkTitle}' in this pdf.")
    #     return

    try:
        # Selecting the first, top parent bookmark.
        bookmark = [annotation for _, annotation in metaObjects.items() if '/Title' in annotation][0]
    except IndexError:
        print("There are no bookmarks in this pdf.")
        return

    # Each bookmark is the child of the previous bookmark. They can be accessed from the parent with the '/Next' key.
    bookmarkAnnotations = [bookmark]
    while "/Next" in bookmark:
        if "/Title" not in bookmark["/Next"]:
            break
        bookmark = bookmark["/Next"]
        bookmarkAnnotations.append(bookmark)

    try:
        # Selecting the bookmark we want to add the url to.
        bookmarkToChange = [annotation for annotation in bookmarkAnnotations if annotation["/Title"] == f"({bookmarkTitle})".replace(" ", "\\040")][0]
    except IndexError:
        print(f"There is no bookmark called '{bookmarkTitle}' in this pdf.")
        return

    # Changing the internal PDF commands to point to a url instead of a page.
    bookmarkToChange.A.D = None                                                 # Deletes the page information the 'Go to page' action is pointing to.
    bookmarkToChange.A.S = pdfrw.PdfName("URI")                                 # Changes the 'Go to page' action to an 'Open a web link' action.
    bookmarkToChange.A.URI = pdfrw.objects.pdfstring.PdfString(f"({url})")      # Specifies the url for the 'Open a web link' action.

    # Saving the end result into a new file.
    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(outputPdfPath, pdf)



inputPdf = r"C:\......\first.pdf"
bookmarkedPdf = r"C:\......\second.pdf"
pdfWithWeblink = r"C:\......\final.pdf"

bookmarks = [
    {"Title": "The Phantom Menace", "Page": 5}, 
    {"Title": "Attack of the Clones", "Page": 10},
    {"Title": "Revenge Of The Sith", "Page": 13},
    {"Title": "A New hope", "Page": 18},
    {"Title": "The Empire Strikes Back", "Page": 26},
    {"Title": "Return of the Jedi", "Page": 32}
]

AddBookmarks(inputPdf, bookmarkedPdf, bookmarks)
AddWebLinkToBookmark(bookmarkedPdf, pdfWithWeblink, "Revenge Of The Sith", "https://stackoverflow.com")
```